# How to combine two arrays to create a bigger one in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have two arrays defined and initialized:

```
int array1[2][2]={
    {1, 1},
    {1, 1}
};

int array2 [2][2]={
    {2, 2},
    {2, 2}
};
```

Now I would like to create and initialize another array, but instead of initializing this third array from scratch, I would like to reuse the other two, and index them:

```
int array3[2][2][2]= {
    array1,
    array2
};
```

So that I can use array3[0][0][0] to get 1 and array3[1][0][0] to get 2;

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can't create the array the way you have written. However, you can do this:

```
int array3[2][2][2];
memcpy(array3[0], array1, sizeof(array1))
memcpy(array3[1], array2, sizeof(array2))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to reuse and index the other two arrays is to create an array that stores pointers to `array1` and `array2` like so

```
int array1[2][2] = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
int array2[2][2] = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}};
int (*array3[2])[2] = {array1, array2};

printf("%d %d\n", array3[0][0][0], array3[1][0][0]); // ouptuts 1 2
```

This avoids copying the data and since `array3[0]` points to `array1`:

```
array1[0][0] = 3;
printf("%d\n", array3[0][0][0]);
```

prints 3

Comment: Thank you rpattiso! I was looking for a way not to duplicate the original arrays and this does it.

Answer (score 0):

@rpattiso's answer has a pitfall that array3 does not follow the row-major convention of C language.

This kind of trick will break the code that uses initial address and array size to iterate through all elements in the array.

The reason why I bring this up is that a guy I worked with did something similar. He tried to dynamically allocate a 2D array by using a for-loop of "malloc"s to allocate multiple 1D arrays and then combine them to a 2D array in exactly the same way.

Then when I tried to iterate through the array, assuming it was row-major and contiguous in memory, I got a very nasty heap corruption.

Another less significant issue of this solution is that sizeof(array3) is not sizeof(array1)+sizeof(array2), but 2*sizeof(int**).

Comment: My answer is not a *trick*. It is clear that is an array of pointers, which is very common in C, and should be treated as one. Note that you can comment on peoples answers, and should, instead of posting it as an answer to the question.

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation to make a comment. And it is clear to me, too, that it's not an array. I was just reminding whoever is reading this post that, for it's not an array, it lacks a few array's properties, so don't try to use those properties.